# Could not load type 'System.Environment' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

We are updating from .NET 3.1 to .NET 6.  After deploying the Azure Function App, the "Runtime version" displays, "Error", and the below message is on the overview page.

> Could not load type 'System.Environment' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Answer (score 21):

The solution is to update the function app to version 4.

Updating the following project values to:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

and

Using this command:
`az functionapp config appsettings set --settings FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=~4 -n <APP_NAME> -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>`

source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#migrating-from-3x-to-4x

Comment: Even after updating the project file with <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion> tags, the deployed function app, still gave me this error. So, I had to manually update the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION as ~4 under function app > configurations to resolve this issue.

Comment: @SanushiSalgado this is what I had to do. Went to the configuration section of my FA and changed it from ~2 to a ~4 and that fixed my issue.

Comment: What does FA mean?

Comment: I believe it is an abbreviation for "functions app".

Comment: This answer absolutely nails it. The MS docs on this are ridiculously opaque and/or incomplete, and this project setting tweak is the missing link after upgrading to .NET 6.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition, for anyone like me following these answers in a local development environment; ensure that your Functions Core Tools are up-to-date too. If they're not you'll see the error described in this post, even after updating your functions config. To verify, check the Runtime version when your solution starts (e.g. Function Runtime Version: 4.25.3.21264) and if necessary, update the core tools as described in the MS guidance: [Develop Azure Functions locally using Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)